# How good a memory allocator is this?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

As you know `mmap` and `malloc` are non-deterministic on a system with Address Space Layout Randomization. To make my memory allocation deterministic, I use `mmap` to reserve a very large address space (on a 64 bit system) with no swap space, that is, using MAP_NORESERVE. Then as I require memory, I assign 10 MB of space by doing `mmap` with MAX_FIXED within that address space range. Therefore, the memory allocated grows linearly.

When I need to `free` memory, I just unmap it using use `munmap`. Moreover, I don't reutilize the address space which has been unmapped, but keep on allocating ahead. I guess this doesn't really affect anything as my address space (allocated with `mmap` with MAP_NORESERVE) is very large anyway.

Now, the question is, how good a memory allocator is this. It ofcourse isn't a very smart one, as it cannot allocate small chunks of memories, as through `mmap` you allocate at least 4096 bytes of memory, but I guess its still quite a workable solution. What do you think?

Also, what for the case where a process allocates memory of factor 4096 only. In that scenario, I think this approach wouldn't be inferior to `malloc`.

### EDIT

Note that I'm talking about determinism with respect of two identical redundant processes. One is forked from another, so it gets the initial address of the mmaped region with MAP_NORESERVE, as I do `fork` afterwards.

Comment: I'd say the main question should be: Why do you need your application's memory to be a single block?

Comment: What's the point of this? And why do you think this will be more "deterministic"?

Comment: ThiefMaster, added why I need this in my question.

Comment: `MAP_NORESERVE`? Don't you mean `MAP_SHARED`?

Comment: Darkdust, No, By MAP_NORERSEVE, I really mean MAP_NORESERVE. Also I'm talking about privately allocated memory, therefore MAP_PRIVATE, not MAP_SHARED.

Comment: Your testing will be difficult, because the two processes would be contending for the malloc lock occasionally. You would have to do very long test runs, or artificially make contention more likely.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your goal. I also don't understand why you want to disable swapping, is this for security?

Answer (score 1):

> To make my memory allocation deterministic

An easier solution might be simply [disable ASLR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1460638/50617).

> how good a memory allocator is this.

That very much depends on your quality criteria. As the other answer points out, it's not a very good general purpose allocator. But then a general purpose allocator wouldn't normally have a requirement to be deterministic.

Presumably you have such a requirement, and possibly some other (yet unstated) requirements as well.

Since you've kept us in the dark on *what you are actually trying to do*, we can't tell you whether what you've done is good or not.

Comment: I just noticed who this question is from. I've already made a mental note to *not* answer any of MetallicPriest's questions, because invariably they are rather low-level, very strange, and exceedingly under-specified.

Answer (score 0):

Not good. Sooner or later, you'll run out of virtual memory. Whether it's sooner or later depends on how much your process allocates and frees, but anyway, it surely isn't suitable for a long running daemon.

But this determinism requirement is strange. Even if your memory allocation is deterministic, it depends on the input. If the processes do something in a slightly different order, then results will differ.
And if they do everything exactly the same, how are they redundant? If one would crash, then the other will do exactly the same.

Comment: ugoren, Like i said, its a 64 bit system, where we have virtually unlimited address space, and as far as physical memory and page swapping is concerned, its not like we are not deallocating (freeing) memory at all, but just not doing at a granularity as fine as malloc. That is the only difference I guess. If, say, we have a process which only allocates memory with factor of 4096, then I think this approach is even better than malloc. What do you say?

Comment: Nothing is unlimited. In a 64bit system, it may just take more time to exhaust the memory. Also, the process address space is large, but not 2^64 bytes - it's much smaller. It's large enough for anything reasonable, but not large enough to just keep throwing away virtual memory.

Comment: Its not necessary that if one crashes, the other would to! I mean you may have a soft error, that corrupts data of one process but not of the other. And no one is throwing memory. I do free it.