# Stop Unix Stack Randomization in C

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable address space randomization for a binary on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455904/how-to-disable-address-space-randomization-for-a-binary-on-linux)

Is there a system call / library in C that will stabalize the program's stack, and stop the OS from randomizing the stack 's position?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to disable it? (PS `sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0` appears to work for Gentoo)

Comment: stack randomization is a security measure to mitigate stack smashing attacks. Disabling it essentially opens the front door for malware to walk in.

Comment: @MarcB that's a bit of a drastic slippery slope... I agree that there's virtually no reason to disable it, but it's not opening a front door for malware.

Comment: I am aware of that. I was working on a `buffer bomb` project and was just wondering how they are achieving stack stabilization that allow basic stack-based exploitations work. That's it :)